# ¿Cómo recuperar el usuario root en XAMPP?

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

Tengo un inconveniente: Accidentalmente eliminé el usuario *root* en *XAMPP*, y ahora no puedo ingresar a la base de datos.

¿Cómo puedo recuperar el usuario *root* para volver a ingresar a *phpMyAdmin*?

Comment: bueno puedes crear un usuario con todos los privilegios podría funcionar

Comment: @Kevin no me deja entrar al phpmyadmin no hay manera de ingresar

Comment: @user15759 entra a la consola mysql de xampp. Hay varios videos tutoriales sobre ello :)

Comment: Es posible que este link te ayude. https://www.fmunifer.com/root_phpmyadmin_xampp/

Answer (score 2):

En el directorio de *XAMPP* en la carpeta *MySQL* hay un archivo **resetroot**. Este resetea el usuario *root*. Posiblemente te pueda ayudar a recuperar el usuario.